# how find all function $f:(0,+\infty)\to(0,+\infty)$ that satisfy in following conditions?

Tags: functions, contest-math

how find all function $f:(0,+\infty)\to(0,+\infty)$ such that $\forall w,x,y,z\in \mathbb R^+  ,wx=yz$$$\frac{f(w)^2+f(x)^2}{f(y^2)+f(z^2)}=\frac{w^2+x^2}{y^2+z^2}.$$Thanks for any hint .

Comment: IMO 2008 problem 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Try $w=1$, $y=z = \sqrt{x}$.